# C# consume complex type from soap webservice

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, soap

I have consumed a webservice in VS2010 C#.  Within the WSDL there are a few complex types, one of which is defined as:

```
<element name="dsPageInfo">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ttPageInfo">
        <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element name="PageTitle" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="MetaTitle" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="MetaDescription" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="MetaKeywords" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
      </element>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

To define and call this in VB:

```
Dim webService As New myWeb.wsObjClient()

Dim systemType As String

Dim ds(0) As myWeb.dsPageInfoTtPageInfo

webService.Getpageinfo(systemType, ds)
```

What's the equivalent to `Dim ds(0) As myWeb.dsPageInfoTtPageInfo` in C#?

So far I have:

```
string systemType = "mySysType";
myWeb.wsObjClient webService = new myWeb.wsObjClient();

webSevice.Getpageinfo (
    systemType,
    // complex type goes here);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent for creating the array in C#

```
myWeb.dsPageInfoTtPageInfo[] ds= new myWeb.dsPageInfoTtPageInfo[1]

ds[0]= new dsPageInfoTtPageInfo();
webSevice.Getpageinfo (systemType,ds);
```

Comment: With the addition of ds[0]= new myWeb.dsPageInfoTtPageInfo(); Spot on thank you.